# How to detect (when trying to append a created element) if that element has been created once before with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm trying to build a gif/webm/png etc viewer, right now I'm creating elements to then set the file selected to that `img` (or if it is a ***webm*** file, then we'll set it's src to a `video` element)

Now I'm also building a hide button (the element I want to see if it's already appended) to hide the image or video when it is clicked, so I want to create it... then append it when an image like a `gif` or `png` is chosen, but I have made a listener to detect if the file is a webm.

I also want to detect if the document already has the hide button, so therefore I can assign a hide button to either the `img` element or `video` separately element because as on my [codepen](https://codepen.io/novaappsinc/pen/qBPVKQV)
the hide button won't work to hide the `video` when the `img` is created first then the `video` and so forth.

Basically I want to detect if the hide button has been appended before for the `img` element and/or `video` element (to prevent duplicates on the page) then delete it and create a new one that will read for the new `video` or `img` element.

Comment: Why are you creating and deleting elements? Create them in the HTML and just update their attributes to change the image or video that they display. You can use CSS to hide and show them when appropriate.

Comment: But the answer to your question is to give the element an ID, and then use `document.getElementById()` to check if the element already exists.

Comment: @Barmar I could change the attributes (which I have done) but that'll also conflict with my current CSS thus making things wonky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after awhile of trying out things, I came to a conclusion that an `if` statement could work.

```
const btnOne = document.createElement("a");
const btnTwo = document.createElement("a");

if(btnOne !== null) {
  if(btnOne.parentNode) {
     btnOne.parentNode.removeChild(btnOne);
  }
  document.body.appendChild(btnTwo);
} else if(btnOne == null){
  document.body.appendChild(btnTwo);
}
```

this is basically how I did it.